# easy-to-use image-editing FLOSS

Tags: software-rec, images, image-editor

I'm looking for recommendations for something easy to use that will allow me to edit my images. I fiddled with Inkspace and GIMP and found them not so intuitive (I don't want to have to read a manual to know how to **draw a border** around some part of the image).

Comment: gimp is worth the effort, it is a good piece of sw. Not the most user friendly but quite competent :)

Comment: @Johan, I'm sure it is, and so is Inkscape. I just hate being frustrated, that's it.

Comment: You can wine mspaint, I did that a long time ago when I was unwilling to make myself learn gimp :)

Comment: Can you give more details on the level of editing that you want to do? There's a trade-off to make between the level of complexity in the editor and how advanced its features are. Pinta, the program you selected, is around the middle of that balance, but I think it would help other people reading this question to know precisely what you were looking for.

Comment: @Matt, just highlighted the part that concerned me, which I couldn't figure with GIMP or Inkscape.

Comment: In gimp, make a rectangle selection, then in menu edit you find "Stroke Selection..." and that will paint the rectangular selection.  But then gimp is for photo editing and not painting...

Comment: @Johan, now that's what I call not easy-to-use. How would an inexperienced user guess she had to select "Stroke Selection..."? With Kolourpaint or Pinta, I just selected rectangle and was able to draw right away. +1 for the 'answer' though.

Comment: @Tshepang, you are totally right, but on the other hand this way you can then decide how you would like to draw that line and what effect you would like to use... etc etc. so it is very flexible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what exactly do you need to do with your images...

If you want something like mspaint you could try Kolourpaint (from KDE)...

If you want process photos (change brightness/crop/etc) I'll recomend Digikam - it is digital album (like f-spot or picasa mentioned before) with lot of tools to change properities of photos - crop, change brightness, denoise etc...

Comment: +1 for Kolourpaint. More mature than Pinta.

Comment: also Krita since this seems to be about KDE imaging apps.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/), its interface is pretty similar to MS Paint's.

Comment: quite immature at the moment, but pretty much fits the ease-of-use I was looking for; thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, some of the programs include:

- f-spot
- gthumb

They are easy to use but their options are pretty poor comparing to Inkscape or Gimp (even though Inscape is used for vector editing and Gimp for raster).

Have in mind that Gimp is **worth** trying a little harder because when you master its basic functions, it will boost your image editing on a daily basis. If you dont like current UI of Gimp, use v2.7 to get single window UI (like Photoshop). 
Here's [a bunch of nice and free PDFs for Gimp usage and stuff](http://www.tuxradar.com/gimp).

Comment: Picasa isn't FLOSS is it? If so, why mention it?

Comment: Uh sorry, my bad Tshepang. I removed it now :)

Comment: I removed the requirement for FLOSS.

Answer (score 0):

Is you would like it to be **fast**, best is using a shell tool like `imagemagic`, maybe combined with a short script to create the options for imagemagice.

Whether this approach is feasible, depends heavily on properties of use case. 
It can be anything between obviously easy to do, and obviously impossibe.

The range in between is large and diverse - I would like to explain for your case,
what  I woud expect.

Please explain as clearly as possible what problem has to be solved, and your Idea of what schould happen. An important aspect is, whether there factor involved that cause variation in the tasks.

Best wishes for now!